# Using auto-generated classes with no toString implementation

Tags: java, design-patterns, tostring

I have a few auto-generated classes(models) as part of a core service that I am integrating. However, the authors of those classes have intentionally/unintentionally left the *toString* method overriding.
I have a few options on how to use these classes on which I need some insight.

1. I can make exact duplicates of those classes in my packages overriding the *toString* method and add those auto-generated classes in .gitignore. However, the caveat with this approach is that any future changes in those classes will not be reflected in my code and new developers may be oblivious to the incompatibility in the service and my implementation.
2. I can create a wrapper class for the top level classes and add toString but then I have to call getters for every single method and if it contains nested classes that might lead to a sort of a flat-map creation. (Chaotic *toString method)*
3. I was thinking of using the decorator pattern (adding functionality to a class without breaking it), but I'm not sure if this is how it is intended to be used.

I'm positive that I'm not the first one who came across this problem, so there must be some sort of a ***right way*** to tackle it. A nudge in that direction would be helpful.

---

**EDIT**
So far I've observed that the only way is to change the bytecode or use reflection. However, changing the bytecode would only fix things for the classes affected not for all the (future as well) classes.
Instead, I have written a custom logger which implements *org.slf4j.Logger* and overrode the info level logging such that, it:

- Behaves the same for all the object which have the toString method 
  overridden
- Parses the object to Json using jackson library and concatenates that Json to the string
  argument provided

Although jackson internally uses reflection to convert pojo to json, I'm only doing this in cases where I don't have myobject.toString().

Here is the implementation of my custom logger.

```
public class MeinLogger implements Logger {
private static final String REGEX_CURLY = "\\{}";
private static final String TO_STRING = "toString";
private static final String CURLY_ALTERNATE = "REGEX_CURLY";
    private final Logger superLogger;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public MeinLogger(Class<?> className) {
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        this.superLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(className);
    }

    @Override
    public void info(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void info(String s, Object o) {
        boolean toStringImplemented = false;
        try {
            if(checkToStringAndReturn(o).equalsIgnoreCase(CURLY_ALTERNATE))
                toStringImplemented = true;
            s = s.replaceFirst(REGEX_CURLY, checkToStringAndReturn(o));
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | JsonProcessingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        s = s.replaceAll(CURLY_ALTERNATE, REGEX_CURLY);
        if(toStringImplemented) {
            superLogger.info(s, o);
        } else {
            superLogger.info(s);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void info(String s, Object o, Object o1) {
        List<Object> implementedClasses = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            if(checkToStringAndReturn(o).equalsIgnoreCase(CURLY_ALTERNATE))
                implementedClasses.add(o);
            s = s.replaceFirst(REGEX_CURLY, checkToStringAndReturn(o));
            if(checkToStringAndReturn(o1).equalsIgnoreCase(CURLY_ALTERNATE))
                implementedClasses.add(o1);
            s = s.replaceFirst(REGEX_CURLY, checkToStringAndReturn(o1));
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        s = s.replaceAll(CURLY_ALTERNATE, REGEX_CURLY);
        if(implementedClasses.size() > 0)
            superLogger.info(s, implementedClasses.toArray(new Object[0]));
        else
            superLogger.info(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void info(String s, Object... objects) {
        List<Object> implementedClasses = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object obj : objects) {
            try {
                if(checkToStringAndReturn(obj).equalsIgnoreCase(CURLY_ALTERNATE))
                    implementedClasses.add(obj);
                s = s.replaceFirst(REGEX_CURLY, checkToStringAndReturn(obj));
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | JsonProcessingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        s = s.replaceAll(CURLY_ALTERNATE, REGEX_CURLY);
        if(implementedClasses.size() > 0)
            superLogger.info(s, implementedClasses.toArray(new Object[0]));
        else
            superLogger.info(s);
    }
```

Comment: Decorator doesn't apply here. Decorator adds behaviour to an existing method, you are talking about about overriding it.

Comment: You could use a bytecode manipulation library to add the toString method to the classes you wan't.

Comment: just a thought - can't you create a `Stringify` class/method that would do that logging for example?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt responses. But bytecode manipulation and reflection (I guess Stringify uses reflection) sound like workarounds. Isn't there a proper way to handle logging of objects which don't implement toString?

Comment: You can follow your 1st option but should write a tool to process the auto-generated files (remove the `toString()` method).

Comment: @NghiaBui Do you mean that I should write a tool to automatically copy the auto-generated classes adding toString method? These are wsdl files and I would need to check whether such an implementation can be done in my maven settings. If it works, this can be a good approach. I will try this and update.

Comment: 1) if you want me to know I got a message from you - tag via `@Eugene`... 2) In your code do something like `public void printMyDToWithoutToString(DTO dto) {....}`

Comment: @PiyushShandilya yes, that's right! Hope it works.

Comment: You should probably fix the tool that's generating your classes in the first place.

Comment: @MattTimmermans The tool is out of bounds. Basically, this is a service that provides APIs to access a huge database which can sometimes be updated manually, hence causing corrupt data or missing parameters. Now the libraries shared via the wsdl were written years back and are not accessible or up for change/improvement. This is why I need logging if the data received is proper or not because it may be missing some values.